# Xcode loses connection to iPad when recording its screen via QuickTime

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan, quicktime

I am deploying an app onto the device from xcode. Xcode loses connection to the device and will quit the program when I try to record device's screen via QuickTime player.

Is there any way to deploy app onto device and exit the debug mode.

Comment: have you found a solution to this? im experiencing the same issue

Comment: @CharlieNorris No luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a project in xcode and click `Edit Schema` and uncheck the `Debug executable` option. This will remove the link between app and debugger once the app is launched. Now if you try to mirror the screen, app doesn't crash.

Answer (score 5):

I've actually solved the issue I was facing.

1) I was selecting "New Screen Recording" when in fact I should have selected "New Movie Recording". Then choose your device as the camera source.

2) Be sure to do step 1 BEFORE deploying the app from XCode.

Comment: I am currently using this workaround but for my actual automated scenario, I have to launch the app and then start recording. I recently found another workaround and I am posting that in comments below